# Thread Pool hanging up on json.loads when multiple json objects are sent

Tags: python-3.x, threadpoolexecutor

I am currently in the process of making a simple server using Python 3.x. I am using a thread pool since there may be a high number of clients connected at any given time. The client sends a json object to the server where it is then parsed out and handled. However, when I send multiple json objects using sendall from the client, the server hangs up and will not process the json.loads in the handle_client function.

This is just an example as I am learning how to use sockets and thread pools in python. Eventually I'll need to have persistent connections. Any explanation as to why it hangs up is much appreciated. Thanks!

**Server**

```
import sys, socket, threading, json, time, concurrent.futures

HOST = socket.gethostbyname(socket.gethostname())
PORT = 65000
TIMEOUT = 5
MAX_CLIENTS = 5
BUFFER_SIZE = 1024
ENCODING_TYPE = 'utf-8'

clients = []

server = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
server.bind((HOST, PORT))
server.settimeout(TIMEOUT)
server.setblocking(0)
server.listen(MAX_CLIENTS)
print("Server started successfully")

Pool = concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=5)

def handle_client(client):
    if client not in clients:
        clients.append(client)
        print('%s clients connected.' % len(clients))
    while True:
        data = client.recv(BUFFER_SIZE).decode(ENCODING_TYPE)
        if data:
            jsonObj = json.loads(data)
            client.sendall('Keep up the great work!'.encode(ENCODING_TYPE))
        else:
            clients.remove(client)
            client.close()
        print('%(name)s is a %(occupation)s!' % {'name': jsonObj['name'], 'occupation': jsonObj['occupation']})

while True:
    try:
        client, addr = server.accept()
        client.setblocking(0)
        Pool.submit(handle_client, client)
        Pool.shutdown(wait=False)
    except BlockingIOError:
        pass

server.close()
print('Server shutdown')
sys.exit()
```

**Client**

```
import sys, socket, json, time

HOST = socket.gethostbyname(socket.gethostname())
PORT = 65000
BUFFER_SIZE = 1024
ENCODING_TYPE = 'utf-8'

client = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
client.connect((HOST, PORT))

data1 = {
        'name': 'John Doe',
        'age': 23,
        'occupation': 'QA Engineer',
        'employer': 'Samsung'
    }
data2 = {
        'name': 'Jane Roe',
        'age': 32,
        'occupation': 'HR Representative',
        'employer': 'Samsung'
    }
packet1 = json.dumps(data1)
packet2 = json.dumps(data2)

client.sendall(packet1.encode(ENCODING_TYPE))
client.sendall(packet2.encode(ENCODING_TYPE))

while True:
    response = client.recv(BUFFER_SIZE).decode(ENCODING_TYPE)
    print(response)

client.close()

print('Client terminated')
```

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of issues here, but I think your problems begin with this line:

```
server = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
```

It is important to understand what this line means.  You are creating a [TCP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transmission_Control_Protocol) socket.  TCP is a "stream-oriented" protocol.  That means it does not have any concept of "packets."  `send()` and `sendall()` push bytes into the socket, and `recv()` pulls bytes out of it.  After bytes have been pushed into the socket, TCP makes no effort to keep track of "which `send()`" a byte came from.

If `a` and `b` are both `bytes` objects, `sendall(a); sendall(b)` is exactly equivalent to `sendall(a+b)` (there are significant performance differences, which I am intentionally ignoring).  Similarly, `recv(1024)` means "grab the next 1024 bytes from the socket, or give me less than that if you don't have 1024 bytes yet."  If the peer did two sends in a row, then recv may combine them together, or it may not, depending on timing (and other factors such as [Nagle's algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nagle%27s_algorithm)).  Similarly, a very large send might be split up into multiple recvs (even if the buffer size is large enough).

In general, when designing a protocol on top of TCP, you must take care of certain bits of "paperwork" to ensure that everything works smoothly:

- Most protocols have a notion of "messages."  For example, HTTP has [requests and responses](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Messages), and both SMTP and FTP have commands.  In your protocol, the client is sending JSON objects and the server is sending a fixed string; for you a "message" would be either one JSON object, or one instance of that fixed string.
- Normally, each peer alternates between sending and receiving messages until the connection is closed, though more complicated arrangements are possible.

  - If either peer is to receive multiple messages in a row, it must be able to tell where one message ends and the next one begins, preferably without a lot of complicated string manipulation.  This is why many protocols prefer to alternate.
- While receiving, a peer must ensure that it has received the entire message before sending anything (or else the other peer will send more data, and now you're back to the "find where the message ends" problem).  This may require concatenating the results of multiple calls to `recv()`.  The peer must be prepared to deal with partial messages gracefully, for example:

  - It is possible (if moderately unlikely) for a multibyte UTF-8 character to be split up.  Such a byte sequence will fail to `.decode()` with a `UnicodeError`.
  - It is possible for a JSON object to be split up.  Such a character sequence will fail at the `json.loads()` with a `ValueError`.
- With nonblocking sockets, it is not sufficient to call `recv` until it fails with `BlockingIOError`, because later packets may have been delayed or deliberately held back for performance reasons (small packets are relatively expensive).  The receiving peer must actually examine the data received so far and check whether it is a complete message.

Finally, here are a few other observations I have about your server code:

- I'm not sure what `handle_client()` is doing.  It appears to drop into an infinite loop, in which it repeatedly `.close()`s the client's socket, then tries to recv from it again anyway.  That is illegal.
- Similarly, your top level code repeatedly `.shutdown()`s the pool, then tries to submit more tasks, which is also illegal.
- If you use non-blocking I/O, you probably also need to have a call to [`select()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/select.html#select.select) or [`poll()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/select.html#select.poll) in order to detect when the clients are ready for reading.  As your code currently stands, you abandon them.

Comment: Thanks, Kevin. I really appreciate your reply! I'm pretty new to networking and even newer to Python. I just purchased a book teaching networking in Python, but looking at the index it doesn't appear to go that far in depth. Pretty much just shows how to do a chat server. I've taken a networking class in college where we learned how to use headers with packets, and what not. Would you happen to have any recommendations learning more in depth with the things that you are talking about? I think the biggest struggle will be how to handle data that doesn't get received at the same time.

Comment: @Skyler: Actually, I would suggest you start with something easier, like implementing a [TFTP](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc1350) server.  That uses UDP, which preserves packet boundaries and does not require manual buffering.  Once you are comfortable with that, you can move on to implementing things on top of TCP such as your simple chat server.  You might also take a look at [Python's built-in HTTP server](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.7/Lib/http/server.py) for another example of a TCP-based service.

Comment: will do, thanks again! I think that is a good plan. I'm trying to create a base server engine for the online games I make so that I do not have to continue developing a server for each game. I chose to do it in Python and run it on a raspberry pi. I started learning Python for this project. Something I thought would take a few weeks or a couple of months has proved more difficult than I imagined haha.